# iPhone 3G wont connect through 3G network. 

Tags: iphone

My recently bought iPhone 3G (from a third party), is not connecting through the 3G network (Virgin Mobile in the UK). Everything is switched on, 3G, Mobile data etc. but it just wont seem to work. I am using a SIM card taken from my BlackBerry phone.

It's really frustrating because I can't use the intternet whilst I'm outside and must wait until I connect to a WiFi.

What is causing this? What can I do to solve this issue?

Comment: I would start with an article like [this](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS3780) and see if you can narrow down the one step that is failing you....

Comment: You should go to a retail location for your carrier and talk to them. Your phone may be missing a SIM card or it might be locked to a different carrier.

Comment: I have my contract for a blackberry originally but swapped with him +£60. I'm on Virgin. Because of this reason i can't ask them about the problem because i'm meant to be using a blackberry? I've just switched my sim to this iPhone

Comment: Your carrier is primarily motivated to keep you paying your bill. I suspect they will be quite helpful if you want to bring a new device onboard your account. Apple also provides excellent help if you are adamant about not seeking the carrier's help (where this issue largely rests.)